# getting 403 error while connecting to sharepoint using python, below is the code im using

Tags: python

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

root_url = "https://company.sharepoint.com"

headers1 = {'accept': "application/json;odata=verbose",'content-type':"application/json;odata=verbose",'odata' : 'verbose','X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED' : 'T',}
re = requests.get(root_url + "/_api/contextinfo",auth= HttpNtlmAuth("username","password"),headers=headers1)

print(re.status_code)
```

Comment: 403 mean forbidden so you don't have access to it, if you know what the api required(maybe authorization in header) then you can call it

Comment: i opened the url in browser with the credentials and it worked. but when i run the python script it is giving 403 error